# how to authenticate a user for a delete action in django testing

Tags: django

I'm getting an error while trying to login via a test. On the frontend I am able to delete a cartItem without no issue but on testing, the test suite can't logged in to do a delete action.

error

```
        with self.login(username=user.username,
>                       password=user.password):

applications/startupconfort/tests/test_frontend.py:137: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
env_python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/test_plus/test.py:238: in login
    return login(self, *args, **credentials)
env_python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/test_plus/test.py:66: in __init__
    "login failed with credentials=%r" % (credentials)
E   AssertionError: False is not true : login failed with credentials={'username': 'helloworld', 'password': '(password)'}
```

test.py

```
def test_auth_user_can_delete_his_cartitem(self):
    user = mixer.blend(
        User,
        username='helloworld',
        password='(password)',
        email='adddd@gmail.com')
    products = mixer.cycle(3).blend(
        CartItem,
        customer=user)
    self.assertTrue(user.is_authenticated())
    #login attempt
    with self.login(username=user.username, 
                    password=user.password):
        response = self.delete('startupconfort:delete_this_item',  products[0].pk)
        self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
    CartItemDeleteView.as_view(),
    name="delete_this_item"),
```

template(html)

```
  <form class="right" method="POST" action="{% url 'startupconfort:delete_this_item' cartitem.id %}">
```

I am using django-test_plus

Comment: As the error says, the username/password combination are incorrect. Did you create a user with those credentials before calling `self.login`?

Comment: hi @solarissmoke . Yes I did . user = mixer.blend(
        User,
        username='helloworld',
        password='(password)',
        email='adddd@gmail.com')

Answer (score 0):

`user.password` is the hashed password value stored in the database, not the password itself. If you try to log the user in with that, it will fail.

Instead you need to log in with the actual password string:

```
with self.login(username=user.username, password='(password)'):
    # This will log the user in correctly
```

Comment: you can also use `self.client.force_login(user)` to force a login without caring about authentication details.